# control Javascript translation in Google search

Tags: javascript, python, google-search

The code performs a google search using the below **init**.py

```
def search(term, num_results=10, lang="en", lr="lang_en"):
    usr_agent = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

    def fetch_results(search_term, number_results, language_code):
        escaped_search_term = search_term.replace(' ', '+')

        google_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={}&num={}&hl={}&lr={}'.format(escaped_search_term, number_results+1,
                                                                              language_code, lr)
...
```

Some of the returned links use javascript do translate the website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var home = '/de/', root = '/', country = 'ch', language = 'de', w = {
            "download_image": "Bild download (Niedrige Qualität)",
...
```

another example:

```
<script>
                dataLayer.push({
                    'brand' : 'Renault',
                    'countryCode' : 'BE',
                    'googleAccount' : 'UA-23041452-1',
                    'adobeAccount' : 'renaultbeprod',
                    'languageCode' : 'nl',
...
```

Is there a way to filter out the results translated through javascript and get search results only in one language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies. Please disregard this question. I made a trivial mistake of putting tripple quoted comments inside a function in another part of the code. It disabled the parameters to be passed effectively.

After removing tripple quote comment from below, I get the results only in english:

```
for google_url in search(query,  # The query you want to run
                lang='en',  # User interface language (host language)
                num_results = 10,  # Number of results per page
                lr="lang_en"  # Langauge of the documents received
'''
lr - parameter is implemented in __init__.py of googlesearch
    It should be handled only here.
Other useful search parameters not used yet are:
cr - restricts search results to documents originating in a particular country.
    (ex. cr=countryCA)
gl - boosts search results whose country of origin matches the parameter value.
    (ex. gl=uk)
'''
                ):
```